# Why the connect() in android socket does not work?

Tags: android, sockets, exception, connect, wifi-direct

I wrote similar codes as the demo of Android WiFiDirect, but my socket.connect() cannot work. It terminated and jumped into the "finally" section without throwing any exceptions. I checked all the input parameters of connect(), and they are exactly the same as those in the demo.

Does any guy encounter this similar problem? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It would help if you could show us some code, as it's hard to say anything with only guessing.

Comment: have you given INTERNET permission ? upload your code with error logs

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. The details are given below.

Exception can cover more than IOException; using Exception, the problem description was caught. The socket terminated because the connection of socket cannot be run in UI thread in the latest SDK version. A worker thread was opened to do the socket stuff and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it has thrown a `RuntimeException` such as `SecurityException` that you don't have a catch block for.